# html css mega menu drop down

Tags: html, css, menu, zurb-foundation-5

http://www.brokenarrowwear.com/responsivedesign/index.html

I'm redesigning this website and I'm having a problem with the product catalogue drop down menu. I'm using `foundation 5` for responsiveness, and I'm not sure but it may be what's messing up my menu.

The code I'm inserting doesn't work on the thing on here (I'm assuming because I can't get foundation and pictures to load in) but the link has what it looks like.

I've tried a lot of different methods to get this to work with just editing the CSS. I thought it was a margin thing but when I right click for inspector view it shows an anchor tag where I didn't code an anchor tag which made me really confused.

Can anyone help me? ps the menu product catalog drop down is supposed to look like this.
[image: product catalog drop down]

```css
/* MENU */
.button-group {
 width: 104%;
 letter-spacing: .014em;
}
.button-group .button {
    font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;

    background: #5fd6d6; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #5fd6d6 0%, #b9e8e8 42%, #b9e8e8 57%, #5fd6d6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5fd6d6), color-stop(42%,#b9e8e8), color-stop(57%,#b9e8e8), color-stop(100%,#5fd6d6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #5fd6d6 0%,#b9e8e8 42%,#b9e8e8 57%,#5fd6d6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #5fd6d6 0%,#b9e8e8 42%,#b9e8e8 57%,#5fd6d6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #5fd6d6 0%,#b9e8e8 42%,#b9e8e8 57%,#5fd6d6 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #5fd6d6 0%,#b9e8e8 42%,#b9e8e8 57%,#5fd6d6 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5fd6d6', endColorstr='#5fd6d6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
.buttonleft {
 border-top-left-radius: 8px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.buttonright {
 border-top-right-radius: 8px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

.button-group .button:hover {
 background: white;
 color: #5fd6d6;
 font-weight: bold;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
.menu ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
.menu li a {
 display:block;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: transparent;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.menu li:hover a {
 background: white;
 color: #5fd6d6;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.menu li:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
.menu li:hover ul a {
 background: white;
 color: #161616;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
.menu li:hover ul a:hover {
 color: #161616;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
.menu li ul {
 display: none;
 z-index: 100;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
.menu li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.hidden li {
 width: 96%;
 height: 461px;
 background-color: white;
}
.hidden li img {
 margin-top: -55px;
}
.hidden
{
    left:0px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -2px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
.menu ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}



.dropdownhr {
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.minipics {
 height: 34px;
}
/* tshirt printing drop down option */
.tshirtdropdown:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}
.tshirtdropdown {
 height: 378px;
 padding-top: 75px;
 margin-top: -66px;
}
.tshirtdropdown img {
 width: 100%;
}
.ddheader {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.tshirtbtext {
 color: #cc0b12;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: -55px;
}
/* /tshirt printing drop down option */

/* all over printing drop down option */
.alloverdropdown:hover {
 background-color: pink;
}
.alloverdropdown {
 height: 373px;
 padding-top: 74px;
 margin-top: -61px;
}
.alloverdropdown img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 253px;
}
/* /all over printing drop down option */

/* embroidery drop down option */
.embroiderydropdown:hover {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.embroiderydropdown {
 height: 373px;
 padding-top: 74px;
 margin-top: -61px;
}
.embroiderydropdown img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 253px;
}
/* /embroidery drop down option */

/* rhinestone drop down option */
.rhinestonedropdown:hover {
 background-color: #B19CD9;
}
.rhinestonedropdown {
 height: 373px;
 padding-top: 74px;
 margin-top: -61px;
}
.rhinestonedropdown img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 253px;
}
/* /rhinestone drop down option */

/* product catalog drop down option */
.topproducts:hover {
 background-color: lightgreen;
}
.productitem:hover {
 background-color: lightgreen;
}
.productcatalog {
 width: 1073px;
}
.topproducts {
 height: 413px;
 width: 390px;
 float: right;
 border-left: solid 1px #DDD;
}
.topproducts img {
 width: 350px;
 height: 450px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.productgroup {
 width: 560px;
 height: 413px;
 margin-right: -55px;
 float: left;
}
.productitem {
 width: 161px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-top: 0px;
}
.productitem p {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/* /product catalog drop down option */

/* /MENU */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- menu -->
<div class="row hide-for-small hidden-for-medium-only">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="button-group">
    <li><a href="#" class="button buttonleft">T-Shirt Printing</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-4 columns tshirtdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" style="margin-top: -95px;"/><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Screen Printing</p>
            <p>The most used and traditional method for t-shirt printing. Almost always the most cost efficient!</p>
            </a></div>

            <div class="large-4 columns tshirtdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" /><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Digital Printing (DTG)</p>
            <p>Create high detailed/photographic images with DTG printing.<br />No Mimimums!</p>
            </a></div>

            <div class="large-4 columns tshirtdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" /><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Special Effect Printing</p>
            <p>Glitter, foils, shimmers and reflective just to name a few! Make your design stand out.</p>
            </a></div>

            <hr class="dropdownhr"/>
            <img src="img/noartfee.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/turnaround.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/shipping.jpg" class="minipics" />
          </div>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">All Over Printing</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-6 columns alloverdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" style="margin-top: -95px;"/><br />
            <p class="ddheader">All Over Printing</p>
            <p>The most used and traditional method for t-shirt printing. Almost always the most cost efficient!</p>
            </a></div>

            <div class="large-6 columns alloverdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" /><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Design Samples</p>
            <p>Create high detailed/photographic images with DTG printing.<br />No Mimimums!</p>
            </a></div>

            <hr class="dropdownhr"/>
            <img src="img/noartfee.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/turnaround.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/shipping.jpg" class="minipics" />
          </div>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Embroidery</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-6 columns embroiderydropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" style="margin-top: -95px;"/><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Special Effects</p>
            <p>The most used and traditional method for t-shirt printing. Almost always the most cost efficient!</p>
            </a></div>

            <div class="large-6 columns embroiderydropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" /><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Design Samples</p>
            <p>Create high detailed/photographic images with DTG printing.<br />No Mimimums!</p>
            </a></div>

            <hr class="dropdownhr"/>
            <img src="img/noartfee.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/turnaround.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/shipping.jpg" class="minipics" />
          </div>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Rhinestones</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-6 columns rhinestonedropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" style="margin-top: -95px;"/><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Featured Products</p>
            <p>The most used and traditional method for t-shirt printing. Almost always the most cost efficient!</p>
            </a></div>

            <div class="large-6 columns rhinestonedropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" /><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Design Samples</p>
            <p>Create high detailed/photographic images with DTG printing.<br />No Mimimums!</p>
            </a></div>

            <hr class="dropdownhr"/>
            <img src="img/noartfee.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/turnaround.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/shipping.jpg" class="minipics" />
          </div>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Product Catalog</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="productgroup">

              <div class="productitem"><a href="#">
                <img src="img/productexampledropdown.png" /><br />
                <p>T-Shirts</p>
              </a></div>

              <div class="productitem"><a href="#">
                <img src="img/productexampledropdown.png" /><br />
                <p>Polos</p>
              </a></div>

              <div class="productitem"><a href="#">
                <img src="img/productexampledropdown.png" /><br />
                <p>Hats</p>
              </a></div>

              <br />

              <div class="productitem"><a href="#">
                <img src="img/productexampledropdown.png" /><br />
                <p>Sweatshirts</p>
              </a></div>

              <div class="productitem"><a href="#">
                <img src="img/productexampledropdown.png" /><br />
                <p>Ladies</p>
              </a></div>

          </div><!-- /productgroup -->

          <div class="topproducts"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/topproductsdropdown.jpg" />
          </a></div>

            <hr class="dropdownhr"/>
            <img src="img/noartfee.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/turnaround.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/shipping.jpg" class="minipics" />
          </div>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="button buttonright">Additional Services</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-4 columns tshirtdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" style="margin-top: -95px;"/><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Screen Printing</p>
            <p>The most used and traditional method for t-shirt printing. Almost always the most cost efficient!</p>
            </a></div>

            <div class="large-4 columns tshirtdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" /><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Digital Printing (DTG)</p>
            <p>Create high detailed/photographic images with DTG printing.<br />No Mimimums!</p>
            </a></div>

            <div class="large-4 columns tshirtdropdown"><a href="#">
            <img src="img/dropdownfiller.jpg" /><br />
            <p class="ddheader">Special Effect Printing</p>
            <p>Glitter, foils, shimmers and reflective just to name a few! Make your design stand out.</p>
            </a></div>

            <hr class="dropdownhr"/>
            <img src="img/noartfee.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/turnaround.jpg" class="minipics" />
            <img src="img/shipping.jpg" class="minipics" />
          </div>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /menu -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- /menu -->
```

Comment: "inspector view it shows an anchor tag where i didn't code an anchor tag" This makes me think of an html validation error. Check your code on the w3c validator https://validator.w3.org/